# WPF command pattern

Tags: wpf, command

I have an application wide flag that is an app setting.

```
MyApp.Properties.Settings.Default.SoundMuted
```

The flag is if my apps sound is muted. I have a number of windows where sounds are being played through .Net’s sound player. I was thinking the flag would be wired up to a toolbar button with a command. I was thinking for muting notification to have my classes that play sound wire up to a class (e.g. `SoundManager`) hanging off the app that implements `NotifyPropertyChange`. Then if the user clicks the toolbar button, I would set the Muted property in my `SoundManager` and have all the soundplayer classes get the `PropertyChange` and mute.

Is there a better pattern for this? Say I could wire all the soundplayers up to the command and that command would fire.

Also is there some slick way to just wire that app setting as a bindable property in xaml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I've always done the same approach as in my other answer in knocking up that example I have realized that it is unnesssasary. You can bind to the `Settings` object directly, like this:

```
<Window x:Class="Test_WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:Settings x:Key="SettingsRes"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Menu>
            <MenuItem Header="Audio">
                <MenuItem Header="Mute" IsCheckable="True"
                   IsChecked="{Binding Path=Default.SoundMuted, Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=SettingsRes}}"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Default.SoundMuted, Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=SettingsRes}}" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,156,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Again, multiple instances of that resource still work well together, e.g. bind the `TextBlock` to a second resource:

```
<Window x:Class="Test_WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:Settings x:Key="SettingsRes"/>
        <local:Settings x:Key="SettingsRes2"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Menu>
            <MenuItem Header="Audio">
                <MenuItem Header="Mute" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Default.SoundMuted, Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=SettingsRes}}"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Default.SoundMuted, Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=SettingsRes2}}" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,156,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to make a wrapper class to provide bindable access to the static `Settings.Default`.

**I have since realized this is more work than is needed, please see my other answer**

```
namespace MyApp
{
    internal sealed class ResourceWrapper
    {
        public Settings Default
        {
            get
            {
                return Settings.Default;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, we need to add that as a resource somewhere, could be done in App.xaml, here I've done local to the window that is using it, don't forget the namespace:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"

<Window.Resources>
    <local:ResourceWrapper x:Key="SettingsWrapper"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Now we need to bind to that, this shows it's use in a `MenuItem` on that same window:

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem Header="Audio">
        <MenuItem Header="Mute" IsCheckable="True"
          IsChecked="{Binding Path=Default.SoundMuted, Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=SettingsWrapper}}"/>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Like I said, you can add the resource at the app level or you can create multiple of these ResourceWrappers in different windows/controls, they will all point to the same static underneith.

That full xaml for window with a test `TextBlock`:

```
<Window x:Class="Test_WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:ResourceWrapper x:Key="SettingsWrapper"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Menu>
            <MenuItem Header="Audio">
                <MenuItem Header="Mute" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Default.SoundMuted, Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=SettingsWrapper}}"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Default.SoundMuted, Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=SettingsWrapper}}" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,156,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```